# More rounded corner - Border Radius CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to do more rounded corners in CSS to have a result like this :

[image: the top left corner]

Currently, I have this code:

```
border-radius: 0 400px 0 0;
```

which results in:

[image: the top right corner]

The second value doesn't change the corner even if I put 50px or 1000px.

Is there a way to have a similar border radius?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to elongate your border-radius:

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  
  /* border-top-left-radius: horizontal vertical */
  border-top-left-radius: 50px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius)

Comment: Wow, I must have completely missed that option in years. Interesting!

Comment: Shouldn't the vertical value be `100%`? [Case with 2 lines in div](https://jsfiddle.net/enh06d9n/1/)

Comment: @Pandraghon it's just an example, they can do whatever they like with it, it's just showing OP how to do it, besides, your example is not how the OP wants it - it needs to be a flatter curve

Answer (score 0):

Here another way to do.

```css
.card {
  max-width: 100px;  
  height: 20px;  
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 150px 100px/75px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card "></div>
```